# How to run TypeORM migrations command on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, migration, nestjs, typeorm

I'm writing node.js applications using nest.js and typeORM. I put everything on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and there is no problem here, the API works properly.

I wrote two migrations in typeORM and it's time to run the **typeorm migrations: run** command on the production database. I was looking for help, solutions, tips, but I couldn't find anything specific.

I started to try to set up a second Elastic Beanstalk instance with the code, only instead of the **node main** command I will want to run **typeorm migrations: run**.

This is probably not the best solution, so I am asking you for help. Maybe someone knows how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to run your migrations on your production server is to set `migrationsRun` to **true** in your database configuration.

This will avoid you to run manually the migration command, It will be done automatically on start.

```js
migrationsRun: true
```

Here is an example to use it in your database configuration:

```js
return {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
    port: +process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
    username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    entities:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
        ? ['src/**/*.entity.ts']
        : ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    synchronize: false,
    migrationsRun: true,
    migrations:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
        ? ['src/core/database/migrations/**/*.ts']
        : ['dist/core/database/migrations/**/*.js'],
    cli: {
      migrationsDir: 'src/core/database/migrations',
    },
  };
```

Comment: I don't think that automatically launching the migration when starting the application is a good solution. With CI / CD, migration should be at the right step. The second thing is that you cannot shut down the production application to start the migration.

Comment: This is a bad idea. I am not even surprised though lol